# Loading resources by spring in a websphere application server

Tags: java, spring, websphere

I have a web application running on websphere application server 8 (WAS). In web.xml i have:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:by/example/**/*-ctx.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Then when i deploy my app on WAS - It loads all my ctx files by urls with prefix "wsjar:file..." that is good.

But when in my working app i try to use object of my application context to load resources like this:

```
applicationContext.getResource("classpath*:by/example/**/I-*.sql").getUrl()
```

It's throws exception that url incorrect - but if i add preffix "wsjar:", like  this:

```
 applicationContext.getResource("wsjar:classpath*:by/example/**/I-*.sql").getUrl()
```

It works well. But i need to create universal system to load resources on different app servers, and servlets containers. In tomcat prefix not needed.

How can i load resources in my app on WAS in the same way as ContextLoader via ContextLoaderListener load my ctx files without preffix "wsjar:"?

Answer (score 1):

When i use full package names i have no problems with IBM WAS. Like this:

```
            classpath:com/tdp/abc/facilitador/boost/config/reglaBoostWS-support.xml
```

I didn't try using asteriks for pointing multiple files. Maybe listing all individuals files can work for you.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this.

```
        ApplicationContext appContext = 
       new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"If-you-have-any.xml"});

    Resource resource = 
       appContext.getResource("classpath*:by/example/**/I-*.sql");
```

Comment: The problem is that "Resource resource = appContext.getResource("classpath*:by/example/**/I-*.sql");" IS NOT WORKING ON WAS